# How to print new lines at the end of functions?

Tags: shell, echo, newlines

If I type `echo hello`, my terminal looks like this:

```
My-Computer:~ user$ echo hello
hello
My-Computer:~ user$
```

But if I have a function like this

```
stringen () { cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-Z-A-z-0-9' | head -c "$1" ; }
```

It looks like this

```
My-Computer:~ user$ stringen 18
^\k6JPWVIUdEiudcWSMy-Computer:~ user$
```

See that it doesn't print it in a new line? Same thing when using `printf` vs `echo`. How can I do so that my functions makes new lines like this? I thought that the `;` would take care of this but obviously not.

For example, this returns what I want

```
variable=$(stringen 18)
echo $variable
```

Is it something with echo?

Comment: See: [How to print new line character with echo?](http://superuser.com/questions/443994/how-to-print-new-line-character-with-echo)

Comment: Do you want your prompt to be displayed on the next line every time the output is missing a newline or do you want this to happen only for some particular cases (functions) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither, `cat`, `tr` or `head` adds a newline character (`urandom` could, but it's random so I wouldn't trust it). You have to manually insert the new line, with either a `printf '\n'` at the end of your function, or an `echo`.

BTW, some shells do add it, like `zsh`, to prevent these kinds of situations.

Comment: Absolutely right! I would add a couple of points: (1) The function can be reduced to `{ LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c "$1"; }` (using syntaxerror’s correction to the `tr` arguments). You can put the `A-Za-z0-9` into quotes if you want to, but it’s not necessary. (2) The OP’s `tr` arguments were more badly broken than syntaxerror said. `A-Z-a-z-0-9` means `A` through `Z`, and `-`, and `a` through `z`, and `-` again, and `0` through `9`.

Comment: @Scott: Read the original `tr` argument *thoroughly* again: it was not really "A-Z-a-z-0-9" but `a-Z-A-z-0-9`, big letters *alternating* with small ones. It's not exactly the same thing. So in fact GNU `tr` obviously interpreted a part of it as `...Z-A...`, thus in reverse - and got totally confused as I demonstrated.

Comment: @syntaxerror: I read the original `tr` argument correctly. Sorry if I was unclear. I was making the point that (character)-(character)-(character)-(character)-(character)-(character) was a flawed construct _in addition to_ `a-Z` being an error. And I find it a little funny that you say, “… GNU `tr` obviously interpreted a part of it as `...Z-A...`, … as I demonstrated.” after you said “Hey, how could I be so sure to blame a command with 100% probability? You never can.” You demonstrated no such thing; the error message that you showed says that “`a-Z`” is the problem, not “`Z-A`”.

Comment: Well, when I got that error message on my terminal first time, I seriously thought it might be something in-between of what you pointed out. ;) Anyways...please consider that error messages from system commands may quite frequently be way off the mark, leading you up the garden path. –  –  In a nutshell, chances were that `tr` took the line as-is and parsed it for the *first correct* bit in it from left, which was indeed `Z-A`. So I thought it had read over the `a-` and pretended it wasn't there, just cherry-picking *what* it could interpret properly. (No it wasn't much.)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter in the least if your function prints a newline or not. [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) will remove them if there are any present.

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**. (emphasis mine)

```
testfunc() { echo hello; }    # a newline is printed
output=$(testfunc)            # $output does NOT contain a trailing newline
echo "$output"                # echo adds a newline
printf "%s" "$output"         # no newline
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this might *partly* have to do with `echo` but there's another part of the problem taking influence. So the ideal situation would be if your distro did ship a recent **GNU** version of `tr` (like in mine), because as you can see below, there is a clear quirk in your syntax and GNU `tr` complains to show you where you have to apply the "fix".

original:

```
$ stringen() { cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-Z-A-z-0-9' | head -c "$1" ; }

$ stringen 18
tr: range-endpoints of 'a-Z' are in reverse collating sequence order
```

Ouch! Here is an alternate version of your line which fixes it (at least in *my* distro with GNU `tr` it did the trick):

"fixed":

```
$ stringen () { cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9' | head -c "$1" ; }
$ stringen 18
V068BrYGKIICyLI4QB
$
```

Conclusion: you had better not mix sets with `tr`, but when combining sets/ranges, always make sure that you keep big letters to big letters and small letters to small letters.

**However**: With a non-GNU `tr`, the problem with the missing newline might be still persisting. But with a GNU one, my corrected line will no longer make any fancy newline trickery necessary.

Comment: What version of tr we are talking about? In my system, it isn't adding the newline at the end.

Comment: Oh, good point. Mine is GNU `tr` from `coreutils` v8.23. But anyway: I think this line will also work with non-GNU `tr`, just ... the GNU one appears to be the winner because it shows the user where his syntax problem is and how he can fix it.

Comment: @Braiam There we go again. Thanks to your considerations, I felt like improving my answer w/strictly distiguishing between GNU and non-GNU `tr`.

Comment: I don't know how to see which version but I have a BSD version with a man page from July 23, 2004.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the feedback. Hmmm. Maybe it's a thing related to system locale? Other than that - I confess I'm clueless for now. Still, it's odd you're using the same version and your Arch omits the newline whilst my Lubuntu does print it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had meant with "versions" (or variants if you insist). Anyways, as you can see in my post, I've posted *both* the original and my version to let readers of this answer compare them face-to-face (without having to scroll to top).

Comment: IMNSHO, any version of `tr` that would add a newline in this context is broken. Are you sure it’s `tr` that’s doing it? _(How could `tr` possibly be doing it? It’s almost surely `head` that’s doing it. Still a bug, IMO, but not as terrible a one.)_ While the OP’s arguments to `tr` were clearly wrong, they had nothing to do with his problem.

Comment: Hey, how could I be so sure to blame a command with 100% probability? You never can. But come to think of it, yes, `head` might be the culprit. Besides, reading that the OP's `tr` has a `man` page dated 1 decade ago, it is legit to assume `head` is similarly ancient. ;)

Comment: This has everything to do with `echo`: it prints its argument followed by a newline. `tr` works on binary data and printing an extra newline would be a bug. `head -c` can't print an extra newline either, it strictly prints the requested number of bytes. If you're seeing a newline it must be because your shell is configured to move to the next line before displaying a prompt. Try `stringen; echo more stuff`.

Comment: Just did that. Interesting indeed: `stringen 18 ; echo "BLAH"` gives me a `TmdXxn9oSVXuzliUx1BLAH` output with the "BLAH" immediately following the generated string, which on its part is followed by a blank line. This blank line will (obviously) be omitted once I use the -n option with echo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable to save the output for this. Simply `echo` the output directly :

`echo "$(stringen 18)"`